# Approximation of $\frac{1}{2^{N}} \binom{N}{\frac{1}{2}(N + s)} $ for big N

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, combinatorics, taylor-expansion, approximation

I have the following function that I have to approximate for big N and I really have no clue what to do - I hope that anyone can help me out:

$$P_N(s) = \begin{cases}  \frac{1}{2^{N}} \binom{N}{\frac{1}{2}(N + s)} &\text{N $\land$ s even or N $\land$ s uneven }\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}
 $$

for $N,s \in \mathbb{N}, \ s \le N$. The task is to show that $P_N(s) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi N}} \text{e}^{-\frac{1}{2} \frac{s^2}{N}}$ for big N.

Now I have thought about a Taylor-Approximation but I miserably fail when facing the expanded form of $P_N(s)$:

$$\binom{N}{\frac{1}{2}(N + s)}  = \frac{1}{2^N} \frac{N!}{\left[\frac{1}{2}(N + s)\right]!\left[N - \frac{1}{2}(N + s)\right]!} = \frac{1}{2^N} \frac{N!}{\left[\frac{1}{2}(N + s)\right]!{\left[\frac{1}{2}(N - s)\right]!}}$$

So my problem is that I don't see how to differentiate that - and it remains a mistery for me how I am supposed to get the e-function in there....
When I look at the for big N, I don't see any simplifications either.

I am sorry for not being able to present any useful own thoughts - I really have been thinking about this forever....

Thank you very much for your help,
FunkyPeanut

Comment: This looks like a job for [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Comment: Your expression probably comes from the addition of independent  Bernoulli random variables, which, by the central limit theorem, will converge to a normal distribution (which is that expression with $e$ in it).

Comment: @NovaDenizen Thanks for that. I don't really see how this helps me even though it really seems as if it is at least part of the solution. I tried to approximate all the faculties with $ln(n!) = n ln (n) - n \Leftrightarrow n! = e^{n ln(n)-n} = e^{-n}n^n$. And now I am stuck again... so sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approximate the binomial by a Gaussian:
Binomial[n, s]/2^n  ~  Exp[-(n/2 - s)^2 /2/(n/4)]/Sqrt[2 Pi n/4]

$ \frac{\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}+\frac{s}{2}}}{2^n}$ to $\frac{\exp \left(-\frac{\left(\frac{n}{2}-\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{s}{2}\right)\right)^2}{\frac{2 n}{4}}\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi  n}{4}}}$
and the right side simplifies to $\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} e^{-\frac{s^2}{2 n}}}{\sqrt{n}}$
which differs by a factor of 2 from your P_n(s) above.

Comment: Hmm looks interesting. I am not sure weather that is exactly what I need here - it would be nice if that factor 2 was eliminated. Would you have a suggestion on how to do this with the stirling approximation? Thank you very much nevertheless!

Comment: Always nice to check numericaly: for n~1000 and s~100 I get for the left side 0.000169397 and for right 0.000170007. So I'm rather confident about that factor of two.